# How to break out of an infinite loop while the program is running in python

Tags: python, infinite-loop

I was making something in python that I am not smart enough to make, and I accidentally created an infinite loop, and I can't end it because I am using pygame, so it made a new window and I can't close it. I tried Ctrl+c and closing the lid of my laptop, is there any way other than restarting, because that will be annoying to do every time.

```
(No title)
import pygame

# initialize variables
width = 1366
height = 704
display_surface = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height)) 
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))  
# this is the block type list
items = [
# building blocks
["grass", "dirt", "stone", "ore", "chest", "item collector", "block placer", "item dropper"],
# technical blocks
["wires", "sensor", "AND gate", "OR gate", "NOT gate", "NOR gate", "XOR gate", "XNOR gate", "NAND gate", "gearbox", "gear - 24 tooth", "gear - 8 tooth", "item pipe", "filter pipe", "delete pipe", "motor", "joint", "bearing", "blueprints", "spring"],
]

# initiallize pygame sttuff
pygame.init() 

# begining of program
import pygame

def init_screen_and_clock():
    global screen, display, clock
    pygame.init()
    pygame.display.set_caption('Game')
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()


def create_fonts(font_sizes_list):
    "Creates different fonts with one list"
    fonts = []
    for size in font_sizes_list:
        fonts.append(
            pygame.font.SysFont("Arial", size))
    return fonts


def render(fnt, what, color, where):
    "Renders the fonts as passed from display_fps"
    text_to_show = fnt.render(what, 0, pygame.Color(color))
    screen.blit(text_to_show, where)


def display_fps():
    "Data that will be rendered and blitted in _display"
    render(
        fonts[0],
        what=str(int(clock.get_fps())),
        color="white",
        where=(0, 0))


init_screen_and_clock()
# This create different font size in one line
fonts = create_fonts([32, 16, 14, 8])

loop = 1
while True:  
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    display_fps()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            loop = 0
    clock.tick(60)
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
print("Game over")
```

Comment: You can just add a `break` clause in your loop.

Comment: @PApostol I could, except it is running at the moment and the X button won't make it close

Comment: On Windows ctrl+alt+delete will get you to the task manager from which you can kill the process

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you're setting `loop` to exit/not, but the code is not testing `loop`, it's just testing `True`... which unsurprisingly always evaluates to True.

```
loop = 1
while True:                         # <<-- HERE
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    display_fps()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            loop = 0
    clock.tick(60)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

If you simply change this to test `loop` it will work ok:

```
loop = 1
while ( loop == 1 ):                         # <<-- HERE
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    display_fps()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            loop = 0
    clock.tick(60)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

I laboured the syntax here to show exactly what's going on.  You could also get away with `while loop:`.  But less code isn't always better.